# how to get selected outer text for a select box

Tags: angular, ionic3

i want to get the `outer` `text` of a `select box` when it is `selected`

**for example:**   `<ion-option value="1">Agriculture</ion-option>  // output: Agriculture`

**here is demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-m7jy2n?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

below is my **html**

```
 <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Choose Industry Type</ion-label>
          <ion-select [(ngModel)]="getSelectedValue" (ionChange)="getOuterName($event)">          
            <ion-option value="1">Agriculture</ion-option>
         <ion-option value="2">Chemicals</ion-option>
        <ion-option value="3">Pesticides</ion-option>      
          </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

below is my **controller**

```
    getOuterName(event){
         console.log(this.getSelectedValue);

         alert(this.getSelectedValue);

        console.log(event);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the value attribute.

```
<ion-option>Agriculture</ion-option>
<ion-option>Chemicals</ion-option>
<ion-option>Pesticides</ion-option>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-1caubq?file=pages/home/home.html)**

Comment: but i want `option value`  to `populate` another `select box`

Comment: without removing `option value` any idea?

Comment: you should use an array with two properties and use ngFor

Comment: @EaB did you check